# Xuggler with Tomcat on Windows 7

Tags: windows, tomcat, web, xuggle

I have been developing a web application , here I need to generate thumbnails of videos when they are uploaded by users. I am using Tomcat as my server. So my Tomcat resides in **C:\Apache Tomcat 6** . So do i need to include the jar files of Xuggler in **C:\Apache Tomcat 6\lib** folder ???? and if so which specific jar files do i need to place there ?? which version of Xuggler would be better ? I am not using Maven or Ivy or any dependencies. I am just doing the Web Application in simple Servlet and Jsp concept.

Answer (score 0):

**I will explain how to setup xuggler on localhost tomcat 7**

1. download xuggler jars and all its dependencies.
2. then extract the  .dll files from xuggler.jar(xuggler5.2.jar or xuggler5.4.jar),it is the binary file which is written i c language.
3. copy the .dll files,which is perfect for your system (32bit x86 ,64bit x64) to any folder. for example 
   c:\xuggler.dll
4. Add the path of .dll to the classpath.
5. if you are using eclipse in the build path add path of .dll to the native library path to avoid any issues.

   This could definitely work ,i have done this lot of times!!! 
   please vote if you find my answer useful !!!